# How exactly gsl achieved alternative cblas linking feature?

Tags: gcc, linker, dynamic-linking, linker-errors

Do you know how can I design the same concept that gsl is using to permit users to switch between various cblas implementation?

AFAIK, cblas dependency that gsl depends on should have been hard-coded into gsl library when gsl itself built.

> 2.2.2 Linking with an alternative BLAS library
>
> The following command line shows how you would link the same
>   application with an alternative CBLAS library libcblas.a,
>
> ```
> $ gcc example.o -lgsl -lcblas -lm
> ```
>
> For the best performance an optimized platform-specific CBLAS library
>   should be used for -lcblas. The library must conform to the CBLAS
>   standard. The ATLAS package provides a portable high-performance BLAS
>   library with a CBLAS interface. It is free software and should be
>   installed for any work requiring fast vector and matrix operations.
>   The following command line will link with the ATLAS library and its
>   CBLAS interface,
>
> ```
> $ gcc example.o -lgsl -lcblas -latlas -lm
> ```
>
> If the ATLAS library is installed in a non-standard directory use the
>   -L option to add it to the search path, as described above.
>
> For more information about BLAS functions see BLAS Support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Blas library

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic blas.cpp

gcc -shared -o libblas.so blas.o
```

## GSL library, that is actually using blas but we don't link to it

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic gsl.cpp

gcc -shared -o libgsl.so gsl.o
```

## Example application that links against gsl and blas at the same time

```
gcc -Wall -o main main.cpp -L../mygsl -lgsl -L../mycblas -lblas
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no special concept here – just multiple libraries implementing the same API and having the same ABI.

In other words, you write a program that uses function `int do_stuff(char*)` from `#include foo.h`. `Libfoo.so` is a shared library object that exports the symbol `int do_stuff(char*)`, because it was generated off a program that contains an implementation of `int do_stuff(char*)`.

If you now write a second library that implements all the same symbols that `libfoo` has, then you've got something that you could use in `libfoo`'s place.

That's all that's happpening here. GSL uses BLAS symbols. BLAS defines what these symbols exactly are (read: their C function signature), so you can use whatever BLAS implementation you want. (assuming all was built with compatible compilers/linkers)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was a bit confused how to build gsl library without explicitly linking to the blas library and deferring it to application build time. I made a quick test to verify your claim and it works. Thanks.